# How do I test the contents of a download in RestAssured?

Tags: rest-assured

I have a endpoint I want to test out. I'll call `GET` with it and it's supposed to download a zip file containing a csv file. I want to verify that the contents of that csv file is correct.

When I hit the endpoint in Postman, the headers look something like this:

content-disposition: "attachment; filename=filename.zip"
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 4321
content-type: "application/zip"
vary: Accept-encoding

On the Rest-Assured response though, when I printed out `response.contentType()`, I got `text/html; charset=utf-8`. I was going to try to try to get the response byte in `bytes[]` and then see if it matches the content I'm expecting in the CSV file but since the `content-type` doesn't match what I'm expecting, I don't think I can do that.

Also, how do I check the `content-disposition` of my response?

Comment: I think you generated the wrong request that's why you are getting the different value for contentType. Just check the request packet first or else give me some real code so that I can help you.